# D3 + Leaflet, only draw if visible (big data vis)

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, leaflet

In order to have a reasonable performance with a lot of svg paths, svg text and svg textpath elements on a leaflet map, I wonder how D3 handles elements which are currently not on screen.

So for example when I zoom in to an area such as Washington State, 99.9% of the world is not shown - is D3 default behaviour to draw all the other elements regardless?

I am basing my project on Mike Bostocks [d3 + leaflet example](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/leaflet/). There are no viewports/ viewbox attributes used - is it done somewhere else? Thanks for your input.

Comment: Detection of what should be drawn and not is done in the browser. D3 doesn't handle this at all.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff So there is nothing to optimize?

Comment: I guess it's possible that could squeeze a tiny bit more performance out of it by doing something very clever, but it's almost certainly not worth the effort.

Answer (score 1):

I think there's two parts to this question

1. Drawing of SVG DOM elements that are off screen

   As @LarsKotthoff mentions, it's probably not worth worrying about these, as the browser will probably do a better job than you of optimising them away.
2. Processing of data that will result in SVG DOM elements being drawn off screen.

   I think this is where you can make a difference.  If you have data manipulation/processing that is expensive, then processing things that will not be displayed seems like a waste of cycles.  The only way I can think of improving this situation is to determine as early as possible whether something will be off screen or not.  If it is going to be off screen, then ignore it when doing any further data processing.

   In these situations though, you need a way to detect when it moves into view or out of view and either process or not, as appropriate.  This may result in some additional overhead that makes it not worth doing.

   Your individual situation will determine how effective this can be for you, but if you have a specific example, then users here may be able to assist with re-factoring to help performance.

There are also other things you can do, like re-thinking the visualisation to require less elements in the first place.  In my experience performance has not really been an issue until such a point that there is so much information on screen that the value of the visualisation has been diminished.  Removing the extraneous information has resulted in improved performance and improved comprehension of the visualisation.  Of course, this is my particular experience and there are definitely times when that won't apply.